# Dynamic memory allocation questions with realloc and calloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

See the following function:

```
int go(void) {
   int *p, *q;
   p = calloc(10,sizeof(int));
   q = realloc(p, 20 * sizeof(int));
   <<X>>
}
```

Assuming that both memory allocation function calls are successful, which of the following statements are true at the point marker `<<X>>`.

1. The values of p and q are the same.
2. p points to 10 integers each with the value of 0.
3. q points to at least 80 bytes of memory.

This question is in my C test paper. Except for (2) which is obviously true. I'm quite confused about (1) and (3). Can anybody explain me this?

Comment: Saying something is "obviously true" is an invitation to be wrong. (Read the documentation of `realloc` very carefully.)

Comment: Does (2) have something to do with realloc?

Comment: Knowing your lecturer, all three are to be considered false. (`realloc` can return a pointer that is different to `p`, `realloc` can free the memory pointed to by `p` (so although 2. may often be true, it cannot be relied on), and - as below - we don't know the size of an int (that is why we use `sizeof(int)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brendan said, (1) is not necessarily true (and probably not true).

In C, generally an "int" is 4 bytes, so (3) should be true. It is true on all systems that I know of, although I'm not positive that the C standard says that an "int" must be four bytes long.

Comment: The C standard requires an `int` to be 16 bits or more.

Comment: I assume that you mean 16-bits (2 bytes)? That sounds right to me, so I guess that (3) is not necessarily true (although it is probably true on just about every modern OS).

Comment: Hurp derp, fixed, thanks. 3 is not necessarily true, and neither are 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/realloc.html). Specifically (emphasis added):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion with a size not equal to 0, realloc()
>   returns a pointer to the **(possibly moved)** allocated space. If size is
>   0, either a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be successfully
>   passed to free() is returned. If there is not enough available memory,
>   realloc() returns a null pointer and sets errno to [ENOMEM].

So, the `p` and `q` *may* be the same (if `realloc` is able to resize the existing block of memory), but it's not guaranteed (and so you shouldn't rely on it).

According to the [C standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types), an `int` must be at least 16 bits (2 bytes), so `sizeof(int)` is at least 40, so (3) is not necessarily true.

Comment: Isn't 16 bits = 2 bytes? implying that size will be at least 40 instead of 80

Comment: @James - Maybe for you. It can also be 1 byte, or half of a byte, or some even worse fraction.

Comment: @BrendanLong - The OP's question specifically states that both calls succeed. (You're still right, but put the original logic back in.)

Comment: @ChrisLutz - Ok, I think it's right now.. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ChrisLutz - I learned today that the C standard specifically leaves the definition of the word *byte* ambiguous. +1, Chris!

Comment: @James - Yep. Now go correct people who write `int bits = sizeof(something) * 8` to `sizeof(something) * CHAR_BIT` for the rest of your life. It's a daunting task. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory pointed to by *q* depends on the size of the *int* type, which might not be four bytes.  Statement one is also not necessarily true.  From the `realloc(3)` man page on my system:

> If there is not enough room to
>        enlarge the memory allocation pointed to by ptr, realloc() creates a new
>        allocation, copies as much of the old data pointed to by ptr as will fit
>        to the new allocation, frees the old allocation, and returns a pointer to
>        the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

1) both p and q are pointers.  Look up documentation on what realloc does for the answer.  
3) That statement is ambiguous.  In C, the value of pointers are typically scalar addresses to a byte location.  The size of the memory block allocated is unknown.  The type of the pointer is used to determine the size of a stride when doing pointer arithmetic, but if you allocated a buffer of a multiple size of some type, that is still unknown from the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

Chech these link.These says that 1 may be true or false its like can't say http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/reallo.html

Hope these information helps you as many people already explained about 3rd case

1 is true or false

because q points to the reallocated memory. This may be the same as "p" if the old block of memory could be grown (or shrunk) to the new size; otherwise, it will be a different block. The space begins at an alignment boundary that is suitable for storing objects of any data type. If memory cannot be acquired or if an argument is improperly specified, the NULL pointer is returned.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an exam question, we have to refer to the specification. All three are to be considered false.

1. `realloc` can return a pointer that is different to `p`.
2. `realloc` can will free the memory pointed to by `p` if the newly allocated space is in a different location. This means that p may still point to ten zeros, but this is not what the specification says.
3. As explained well in other answers, we don't know the size of an int (that is why we use sizeof(int)).